# kubectl run - How to pass some commands to be executed before reaching the interactive terminal?

Tags: kubernetes, parameter-passing, kubectl, interactive

When using `kubectl run -ti` with an interactive terminal, I would like to be able to pass a few commands in the `kubectl run` command to be run before the interactive terminal comes up, commands like `apt install zip` for example. In this way, I do not need to wait for the interactive terminal to come up and then run those common commands. Is there a way do so this?

Thanks

Comment: Run an image that already has the tools you want

Comment: Thanks. That is an option that I use. However, I would like to see if that is possible directly from the kubectl run command.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the shell's `exec` to hand control over from your initial "outer" bash, responsible for doing the initialization steps you want, over to a fresh one (fresh in the sense that it does not have `-c` and can optionally be a login shell) which runs after your pre-steps:

```sh
kubectl run sample -it --image=ubuntu:20.04 -- \
    bash -c "apt update; apt install -y zip; exec bash -il"
```